# Visual Studio - Have to hit build multiple times, immediately fails first couple times sporadically

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, build

I am having an issue with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin.

As I am working and hit Build/Rebuild/Deploy, I get stuck in this loop where I have to hit the button in the Build menu 3+ times before it successfully takes.

When it fails, it does not *attempt* to build. It just immediately says that the Build failed in the bottom-most toolbar (where it says *Ready* in the left-hand corner).

*There is no output.*

Then, after a few attempts, the Output window gains focus where it says --- Build Started --- and proceeds as normal without issue.

Has anyone experienced this? Any solution?

It is not an issue with MSBuild project output Verbosity, again there simply *is no output*.

I will mention I am also using ReSharper, and latest version of VS2015, Xamarin, etc.

Comment: Additionally, if I hit build multiple times consecutively quickly, the number of times it takes before it succeeds seems to increase. However, if it fails once, and I wait 10-30 seconds and try again, the second time succeeds.

Comment: Almost like there is a lock on some file unbeknownst to me. 
If I knew which I would run *handle* to identify which process is using it.

Comment: Also, on the failed cases, it switches to the Error List with no errors or warnings present.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: There are no software anti-malware products installed @HansPassant

Comment: Nor is Windows Firewall enabled

Answer (score 0):

I would clean the Debug/bin and Debug/obj folder for any subsequent build.

Comment: Cleaning the *bin* and *obj* folders *may* be resolving the issue, then again the time it takes for me to manually delete them is about the time it takes if I waited between hitting any of the build options.

Comment: I could script out the deletion of these folders so that I could determine that this does indeed resolve the issue, but that begs the question why this is necessary in the first place?

Comment: Target Platforms: Android API 14+
The solution includes PCL, Android and iOS but only loaded projects are PCL and Android.
Configuration Manager: Debug / Any CPU / Build and Deploy

Comment: Also worth noting - *Clean* also fails immediately just like the other *Build* menu options